# compile time config file parsing and setting parameters

Tags: c++, boost

This may be marked as duplicate but i could not locate the correct question if asked already.

What I can do:

1. Runtime parsing of config file and setting parameters
2. can use #defines etc. but I dont want to overload the entire code with hash defines

What i want:

Any method to set parameters in a class (or its members) during compile time. The class is static with typedefs and other static variables (lots of them) - i want to set these values during compile time. (#define etc is not feasible). Can `boost::program_options<..>` be useful?

Comment: No, you need `boost::genie<do_what_I_want>()`. Seriously though, `program_options` is for reading command line arguments. To do what you're asking for will probably involve some kind of custom pre-compilation step where you read a config file and generate a class definition from it. What is wrong with parsing the config file at startup?

Comment: I think the OP is more looking for static-if to replace the preprocessor for conditional compilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple traits, e.g. some default configuration values for any user-defined type:

```
namespace config_traits {
    template<typename ForType> struct enable_serialization : std::false_type {
    };
}
```

Now, consider a user defined type that optionally supports deserialization:

```
class MyConfigurableType {
   typedef config_traits::enable_serialization<MyConfigurableType> enable_serialization;

   std::enable_if<enable_serialization::value, void>::type do_serialization() const {
      std::cout << "Serialized";
   }

};
```

Now you can switch it in a config header:

```
namespace config_traits {

   template<> struct enable_serialization<MyConfigurableType> : std::true_type {
   };
}
```

to enable serialization

---

For the really fancy, you could use a TMP library like `metamonad` and `metaparse` (from **[`mpllibs`](https://github.com/sabel83/mpllibs)**) to actually parse these as settings from a string, at compile time.

I see absolutely no benefit though, except to find compiler limitations.

Comment: So you mean, MyConfigurableType should be the static class with values already set and that i should pass to config_traits so that during compile  time, it will use those parameters and move further ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think code speaks more accurately here. I've added some more explanation text to my answer.

Comment: I understood the compile time type selection, I am not sure what i want is a good coding practice - to read config file fields and set the values in the static class during compile time.

Comment: Oh aha. Well, use any scripting tool that integrates nicely with your build tools, I'd say. People might even use t4 templates or similar to generate the actual source files

Comment: okay. seems no other way that to use scripts to substitute the values. anyways. thanks for the answer.